# Add a check if any checkboxes are selected already w/jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have the following functions that add/remove a style to a button based on whether checkboxes on page are selected:

```
var checkboxes = $(".chkbx").change(function() {
    var allIsChecked = checkboxes.length === checkboxes.filter(":checked").length;
    all[0].checked = allIsChecked;
    enableMyElement(checkboxes.filter(":checked").length > 0);
});

var all = $("#checkall").change(function() {
    checkboxes.attr("checked",this.checked);
    enableMyElement(this.checked);
});

function enableMyElement(b) {
    $("#delBtn")[b?"removeClass":"addClass"]("dis");
}
```

Now, all this works fine but only on change. I need to add a check whether at least one of the checkboxes with class **chkBx** is checked on page load. I was thinking of adding another function, something like this

```
function CheckForAnySelected() {
    $(".chkbx").attr("checked").each( 
        function() {
            // do something
        }
    );
```

...but it does not look like a good solution... and I am certainly not sure how to integrate with my existing code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    function CheckForAnySelected() {    
        if($(".chkbx").filter(":checked").size()>0)
        {
          return true; // atleast one is selected
        }
       else{
      return false;
       });
```

you can use it like

```
if(CheckForAnySelected())
{
//atleast one is checked
}
else
{
// none checked
}
```

here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/QNrZu/13/

Comment: I took jsfiddle example and plugged into my page but I keep getting "one is checked" whether it is checked or not... I also tried using this page's example and get the same results. So I went to the jsfiddle and removed checked on load and still get "one is checked".

Comment: Changed to this and it worked: if($(".chkbx").filter(":checked").length > 0) {

Comment: anyhow it worked in the end `:)` edited the answer so somebody may benefit from it in future, `$(":checked",this)` was not the right selector for it indeed